# Batch Delete Files and Keep Latest One from Subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to search for a specific filename [*dwg] within the "Service" folder and delete all files but the newest one:

- G:\Backup\Owner\Project1\Service
- G:\Backup\Owner\Project2\Service
- G:\Backup\Owner\Project3\Service

This is what I compiled so far from a various searches but haven't been able to get it to search within the subdirectories. Any help or tip pointing me to the right path will be truly appreciated!

```
@echo off &setlocal 
set folder=G:\Backup\Owner
pushd "%folder%"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /a:-d-s /o:-d *.DWG') do @del "%%i"
popd
pause
```

Comment: Do you want to keep just one file for all folders, or one per Project? To see what the dir selects run it in an open cmd window, to see what the del would do prepend it with an echo command.

Comment: Yes, LotPings raises a critical question. Preserving the most recent file from each sub-folder is trivial. Preserving only a single file (the most recent file across all sub-folders) is much more difficult with batch.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Under Project1, I have three extra folders. I'd like to ONLY delete files within the Service Folder hence my decision to include *.dwg in hopes to only target that file.

Answer (score 0):

First and most important issue:

Change `@del` to `ECHO del`

This will simply **report** the deletions proposed, not actually perform the deletion.

Note: `@` before a command simply suppresses the command-logging. Once `@echo off` has been executed, it is redundant.

Now to tackle the (I suppose) leave-the-latest-1-per-directory issue.

```
dir /s /B /a:-d /o:-d *.DWG
```

produces a directory-listing with no directory-names (/a-d) in reverse-date order (/o-d) of filename only (/b) recursing into subdirectories (/s). The colon in options is optional, the case is irrelevant. The `filemask` *.dwg`means "all names ending in`.dwg`" (again, case is irrelevant)

This would yield a listing like

```
d:\dirname\subdir\latest.dwg
d:\dirname\subdir\2ndlatest.dwg
d:\dirname\subdir\3rdlatest.dwg
d:\dirname\subdir2\latest.dwg
d:\dirname\subdir2\2ndlatest.dwg
d:\dirname\subdir2\3rdlatest.dwg
```

And the project appears to be to leave only the first of these within any subdirectory, so we need a switch to tell us that the subdirectory has changed.

`%%~pi` provides the pathname of `%%i`, so we can detect a change there.

We can set a flag easily by `set`ting a variable to well, 1 and 0 or Y and N or whatever - two different values.

The difficulty we will encounter is *interpreting* flags because of the `delayed expansion` issue (Search SO using the facility in the top bar for many items about this)

I bypass the `delayedexpansion` problem by setting flag-variables either to *something* or to *nothing* since that way, they can be interpreted by `if defined`, which operates on the *run-time* value of the variable, not the *initial* value.

Hence,

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
pushd "%sourcedir%"
set "lastdir="
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /B /a:-d /o:-d *.DWG') do (
 CALL SET "keepflag=%%lastdir:%%~pi=%%"
 if NOT defined keepflag ECHO del "%%i"
 set "lastdir=%%~pi"
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

`lastdir` is first set to *nothing* and then the `for` loop assigns each name found in turn to `%%i`.

The `call set` instruction bypasses `delayed expansion` and executes `SET "keepflag=%lastdir:%%~pi=%"` where `%%~pi` has been replaced by the path of `%%i`. This sets `keepflag` to the result of [*the last directory processed* replace *the path of the filename* by *nothing*], which will be a total of *nothing* if the directory-names match and *something* if not.

So, if `keepflag` contains *nothing* then the directoryname did *not* change, so we need to delete the file (or `ECHO` the delete command for safety during testing). If `keepflag` is set to *something* then this is the first file in a new directory, so we keep it by not executing the `del`.

Then we simply set `lastdir` to the pathname from the file `%%i`. That way, another filename in the same directory will set `keepfile` to *nothing* but a change-of-directory will set `keepfile` to *something*.